# How to wrap text around a shape with border-radius?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to auto text wrap with **CSS** the content to avoid cutting-of the text overflowed by a `border-radius`?

At this moment, my text is hidden out the box:

```css
p {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
```

I would like to wrap the text like this image:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. I will think about this

Comment: I think the solution probably lies with `shape-outside: border-box;`. There's meant to be `shape-inside` added at some point which is what you would need, but until then this probably needs a workaround, perhaps using an inverted curved shape and `shape-outside`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Here is a better version using flexbox that will avoid setting any fixed height but require an extra container. The drawback is that part of the text may still overflow. We need to adjust the height accordingly to avoid this:

```css
p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0;
  height:135%; /* we need to adjust this */
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
p:after {
  content:"last";
  color:red;
}

p::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
}

.box {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus
      qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum
      quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem
      quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur
      aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Shape-outside can do this. The only drawback is that it requires a fixed height to work:

```css
p {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:350px;
  text-align:justify;
}
p::before {
  content:"";
  float:right;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  shape-outside:radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left,transparent 98%,#fff 100%);
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
```

You can approximate the perfect height using `vw` unit but still not easy due to the nature of the new shape.

```css
p {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:calc(500px - 20vw);
  text-align:justify;
}
p::before {
  content:"";
  float:right;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  shape-outside:radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left,transparent 98%,#fff 100%);
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
```

A fixed width/height based on the content will give a perfect result:

```css
p {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:310px;
  width:700px;
  text-align:justify;
}
p::before {
  content:"";
  float:right;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  shape-outside:radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left,transparent 98%,#fff 100%);
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
```

[image: CSS shape-outside with border radius]

Here and idea to have curve on both sides:

```css
p {
  border-radius:0 0 1000px 1000px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:310px;
  width:700px;
  text-align:justify;
}
p::before {
  content:"";
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  shape-outside:radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right,transparent 98%,#fff 100%);
}
p span::before {
  content:"";
  float:right;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  shape-outside:radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left,transparent 98%,#fff 100%);
}
```

```html
<p><span></span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
```

[image: CSS text around rounded shape]

---

Related article (I wrote) where you can find more fancy shapes: https://css-challenges.com/custom-text-shape/