# Containing text within border-radius blob

Tags: css

**The problem**: when using border-radius with overflow the text disapears in the corners.

**The question**: Is it possible to contain the text within the border-radius ?

I dont know the length of the text for each page, so the solution needs to work for most scenarios.

```html
<div style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 16px 10px rgba(130,124,110,.25);border-radius: 39% 28% 64% 20% / 28% 16% 57% 66%;max-width:500px;max-height:500px;overflow:hidden;">
  <ul>
    <li>Chuck Norris doesn’t read books. He stares them down until he gets the information he wants.</li>
    <li>Time waits for no man. Unless that man is Chuck Norris.</li>
    <li>If you spell Chuck Norris in Scrabble, you win. Forever.</li>
    <li>Chuck Norris breathes air … five times a day.</li>
    <li>In the Beginning there was nothing … then Chuck Norris roundhouse kicked nothing and told it to get a job.</li>
    <li>When God said, “Let there be light!” Chuck said, “Say Please.”</li>
    <li>Chuck Norris has a mug of nails instead of coffee in the morning.</li>
    <li>If Chuck Norris were to travel to an alternate dimension in which there was another Chuck Norris and they both fought, they would both win.</li>
    <li>The dinosaurs looked at Chuck Norris the wrong way once. You know what happened to them.</li>
    <li>Chuck Norris’ tears cure cancer. Too bad he has never cried.</li>
    <li>Chuck Norris once roundhouse kicked someone so hard that his foot broke the speed of light</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap text around a shape with border-radius?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437000/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-shape-with-border-radius)

Comment: shape-outside does solve the issue. I will mark as solved soon... Interested to see if someone else has other ideas for this.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approximation<sup>1</sup> using `shape-outside`. It's a bit tricky but you need to add more container to be able to have 4 pseudo element to use as floating element and also have a flex container to be able to use percentage height with your floated elements.

The value are approximated based on your case. There is no particular calculation but a simple trial and error

<sub>1: not a perfect solution since part of the text may still overflow</sub>

```css
.box {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.box div {
  height: 100%;
}

.box>div {
  height: 130%;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 16px 10px rgba(130, 124, 110, .25);
  border-radius: 39% 28% 64% 20% / 28% 16% 57% 66%;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 33%;
  width: 40%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
}

.box>div::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  height: 16%;
  width: 28%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
}

.box>div>div>ul::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  height: 75%;
  width: 53%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
}

.box>div>div::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: 78%;
  width: 20%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 500px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Chuck Norris doesn’t read books. He stares them down until he gets the information he wants.</li>
          <li>Time waits for no man. Unless that man is Chuck Norris.</li>
          <li>If you spell Chuck Norris in Scrabble, you win. Forever.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris breathes air … five times a day.</li>
          <li>In the Beginning there was nothing … then Chuck Norris roundhouse kicked nothing and told it to get a job.</li>
          <li>When God said, “Let there be light!” Chuck said, “Say Please.”</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris has a mug of nails instead of coffee in the morning.</li>
          <li>If Chuck Norris were to travel to an alternate dimension in which there was another Chuck Norris and they both fought, they would both win.</li>
          <li>The dinosaurs looked at Chuck Norris the wrong way once. You know what happened to them.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris’ tears cure cancer. Too bad he has never cried.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris once roundhouse kicked someone so hard that his foot broke the speed of light</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Add some coloraiton to the floated element to better understand the puzzle:

```css
.box {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.box div {
  height: 100%;
}

.box>div {
  height: 130%;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 16px 10px rgba(130, 124, 110, .25);
  border-radius: 39% 28% 64% 20% / 28% 16% 57% 66%;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 33%;
  width: 40%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
  background:radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right, red 99%, blue 100%);
}

.box>div::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  height: 16%;
  width: 28%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, green 99%, black 100%);
}

.box>div>div>ul::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  height: 75%;
  width: 53%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left, yellow 99%, purple 100%);
}

.box>div>div::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: 78%;
  width: 20%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right, orange 99%, lightblue 100%);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 500px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Chuck Norris doesn’t read books. He stares them down until he gets the information he wants.</li>
          <li>Time waits for no man. Unless that man is Chuck Norris.</li>
          <li>If you spell Chuck Norris in Scrabble, you win. Forever.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris breathes air … five times a day.</li>
          <li>In the Beginning there was nothing … then Chuck Norris roundhouse kicked nothing and told it to get a job.</li>
          <li>When God said, “Let there be light!” Chuck said, “Say Please.”</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris has a mug of nails instead of coffee in the morning.</li>
          <li>If Chuck Norris were to travel to an alternate dimension in which there was another Chuck Norris and they both fought, they would both win.</li>
          <li>The dinosaurs looked at Chuck Norris the wrong way once. You know what happened to them.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris’ tears cure cancer. Too bad he has never cried.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris once roundhouse kicked someone so hard that his foot broke the speed of light</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```